# jQuery plugin messing with AJAX results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that makes an AJAX call on key up and if the result is not empty it puts it in a tooltip. If I deactivate it everything works as expected, but once enabled AJAX seems to "toggle"  between returning an empty variable and the actual result.

Here is the part that makes the AJAX call and activates the tooltip:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.qty').keyup(function() {
        var qty   = jQuery(this).val();
        var pid = jQuery(this).next().html();
        var element = this;

        jQuery.post('shopping_cart_ajax.php', {products_id: pid, products_quantity: qty}, function(data) {
            if (data)
            {
                jQuery(element).tooltip();
                jQuery(element).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
                jQuery(element).tooltip('update', data);
                jQuery(element).tooltip('show');
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(element).tooltip('destroy');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the plugin itself:

```
(function($) {
var methods = {
    //създаване на tooltip-а
    init: function(options) {
        //настройки по подразбиране
        if (!options)
        {
            options = {
                method: "hover",    //метод за активация на tooltip-а по подразбиране (за момента има само hover опция)
                color: "#dc143c"    //цвят по подразбиране
            };
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            //намиране текста на tooltip-а
            var tooltip_text = $(this).attr("tooltip");

            //добавяне на тялото и стрелката
            $(this).after('<div></div>');
            $(this).after('<div class="tooltip_base">'+tooltip_text+'</div>');

            switch (options.method)
            {
                case "hover":
                    methods.hover(this, options.color);
                break;
            }
        });
    },

    //показване на tooltip-а при посочване с мишката
    hover: function(object, color) {
        $(object).hover(
            function() {
                methods.position(object, color);
                $(object).next().next().fadeIn();   //показване на стрелката
                $(object).next().fadeIn();          //показване на тялото
            },
            function() {
                $(object).next().next().hide();     //скриване на стрелката
                $(object).next().hide();            //скриване на тялото
            }
        );
    },

    //позициониране на tooltip-а
    position: function(object, color) {
        //намиране позицията на елемента, под който трябва да се появи tooltip-а
        var offset = $(object).offset();

        //намиране размерите на елемента
        var parent_width = $(object).outerWidth();
        var parent_height = $(object).outerHeight();

        //намиране размерите на tooltip-а
        var tooltip_width = $(object).next().outerWidth();
        var tooltip_height = $(object).next().outerHeight();

        //намиране вида на tooltip-а и начина на позициониране
        var pos_tooltip_top;
        var pos_tooltip_left;
        var pos_arrow_top;
        var pos_arrow_left;
        var arrow_type;

        if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_top_center") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top-tooltip_height-5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-(tooltip_width/2);
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top-5;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_bottom_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_top_right") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top-tooltip_height-5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-12;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top-5;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_bottom_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_top_left") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top-tooltip_height-5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left-tooltip_width+(parent_width/2)+12;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top-5;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_bottom_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_bottom_center") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top+parent_height+5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-(tooltip_width/2);
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top+parent_height;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+parent_width/2-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_top_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_bottom_right") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top+parent_height+5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-12;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top+parent_height;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+parent_width/2-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_top_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_bottom_left") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top+parent_height+5;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left-tooltip_width+(parent_width/2)+12;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top+parent_height;
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+parent_width/2-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_top_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_left") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top-(tooltip_height/2)+(parent_height/2);
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left-tooltip_width-5;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top-5+(parent_height/2);
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left-5;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_right_arrow";
        }
        else if ($(object).hasClass("tooltip_right") == true)
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top-(tooltip_height/2)+(parent_height/2);
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+parent_width+5;
            pos_arrow_top    = offset.top-5+(parent_height/2);
            pos_arrow_left   = offset.left+parent_width;
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_left_arrow";
        }
        else
        {
            pos_tooltip_top  = offset.top+parent_height+3;
            pos_tooltip_left = offset.left+(parent_width/2)-(tooltip_width/2);
            arrow_type       = "tooltip_no_arrow";
        }

        //позициониране на тялото
        $(object).next().css({
            "top": pos_tooltip_top,
            "left": pos_tooltip_left
        });

        //избиране на подходящата стрелка
        $(object).next().next().addClass(arrow_type);

        //позициониране на стрелката
        $(object).next().next().css({
            "top": pos_arrow_top,
            "left": pos_arrow_left
        });

        if (color != "")
        {
            //задаване цвят на тялото
            $(object).next().css({
                "background-color": color
            });

            var tooltip_class = $(object).next().next().attr("class");
            var arrow_color;

            //задаване цвят на стрелката
            switch (tooltip_class)
            {
                case "tooltip_top_arrow":
                    arrow_color = "transparent transparent "+color+" transparent";
                break;

                case "tooltip_bottom_arrow":
                    arrow_color = color+" transparent transparent transparent";
                break;

                case "tooltip_left_arrow":
                    arrow_color = "transparent "+color+" transparent transparent";
                break;

                case "tooltip_right_arrow":
                    arrow_color = "transparent transparent transparent "+color;
                break;
            }

            $(object).next().next().css({
                "border-color": arrow_color
            });
        }
    },

    //показване
    show: function() {
        $(this).next().next().fadeIn();     //показване на стрелката
        $(this).next().fadeIn();            //показване на тялото
    },

    //скриване
    hide: function() {
        $(this).next().next().hide();       //скриване на стрелката
        $(this).next().hide();              //скриване на тялото
    },

    //промяна на съдържанието на tooltip-а
    update: function(content, color) {
        if (!color)
        {
            color = "#dc143c";
        }

        $(this).attr({
            "tooltip": content
        });

        $(this).next().html(content);

        methods.position(this, color);
    },

    //изтриване на tooltip-а
    destroy: function() {
        if ($(this).next().hasClass('tooltip_base'))
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('tooltip');
            $(this).next().next().remove();
            $(this).next().remove();
            $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }
    }
};

$.fn.tooltip = function(method) {
    if (methods[method])
    {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
    else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method)
    {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    else
    {
        $.error('Method '+method+' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip');
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, if you constantly hover over that tooltip back and forth, you're going to make a bunch of requests. Because they don't immediately return data (instantly), the `success` won't be called until it's finished. This will cause your data to change constantly. **and** in the future, please don't post entire snippets of plugins. You can't seriously expect people to go through that. Link to the github, or resource page.

Comment: The tooltip should be toggled on key up only if the data returned by AJAX is not empty, it's not toggled on hover. I posted the entire plugin because it's custom, there's no official website or github repo.

Comment: +1 for linking to GitHub/source of this plugin, if only so we can clean up that position() function - it's driving me crazy :)

Comment: I know it's far from perfect as it's my first jQuery plugin but it used to get the job done before  this issue appeared. :)

Where should I upload it to?

Comment: How can I make it so the plugin waits for AJAX to actually complete before calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your plugin is related to the issue you are seeing.

Your code initiates an Ajax call **on every keystroke**.

Hence, upon multiple keystrokes, you're then receiving multiple responses one after another, some of which may or may not be empty, which explains the "toggling" effect you're seeing.

What I assume you really want is to only handle the final Ajax **once, only after the user has stopped typing**. Or to say it differently, there should only be one active Ajax request "per purpose" upon any given time.

Hence, you will need to have a reference to the initial Ajax call, and abort it on subsequent keystrokes, then initiate a new one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var xhr;

    jQuery('.qty').keyup(function() {
        var qty   = jQuery(this).val();
        var pid = jQuery(this).next().html();
        var element = this;

        // abort the Ajax request invoked by previous keystrokes
        if (xhr) xhr.abort();

        xhr = jQuery.post('shopping_cart_ajax.php', {products_id: pid, products_quantity: qty}, function(data) {
            if (data)
            {
                jQuery(element).tooltip();
                jQuery(element).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
                jQuery(element).tooltip('update', data);
                jQuery(element).tooltip('show');
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(element).tooltip('destroy');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For your reference, `.post()` returns a jqXHR object [(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), which exposes the `abort()` method [(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

For Ajax calls especially those that are invoked by hovering, or in your case, keystrokes, this is the sort of routine I would always keep in mind: i.e. aborting previous Ajax calls.